# How to rotate image along X axis, in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have an image that I want to rotate along the X axis and when the animation ends, I want to change it to another image.

This 04 second video is an example of what I intend to achieve [Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzyAemyU0Rs)

```
  <Style x:Key="AnimationImage" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX ="1" ScaleY ="1" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="true">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                            From="1" To="-1" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>    </Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Margin="0,25,0,0">
    <Button Name="buPrueba" Content="Rotar" Height="25" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="buPrueba_Click"/>
    <Image Name="imgPeru" Source="/Peru1.png" Height="150" Margin="0,25,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>private void buPrueba_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        imgPeru.Style = FindResource("AnimationImage") as Style;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a combination of scale transform and opacity to manipulate the animation between two images. First image is named "image" here and the second image named "image1" here.

Steps:
1. Start with: image and image1 at same position on a grid. Image is on top of image1. Image1 is at opacity 0% and flipped (`<ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" ScaleX="-1"/>`). These are starting condition, can be embedded into the animation itself at keytime 0. We want to make the image1 invisible and mirror flipped at startup, so that when we rotate again later it will be oriented correctly.

2. Create animation with final state at image1 opacity 100%, image opacity 0%. Image running scale transform on ScaleX from 1 to -1. Image1 running scale transform on ScaleX from -1 to 1. We want to now hide image and make image1 visible while at the same time running ScaleTransform animation on both; one going to +1 while other going to -1.
3. Keep transform origin at 0.5,0.5; i.e. center of the image. We want to keep rotation origin same and at the center.

Following xaml shows the above steps. You can use blend to create similar xaml. Button is here to run the animation. Replace the JPG images referenced in the example code with your actual JPG and right Uri source.

**Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="480" Width="640">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
            <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
            </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="-1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
                <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
            </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="image1" Source="DSC_0068.JPG" Margin="50,50" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" ScaleX="-1"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Image x:Name="image" Source="DSC_0052.JPG" Margin="50,50">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Click="button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25.41,23.25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code behind**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Storyboard storyboard;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.storyboard = this.Resources["Storyboard1"] as Storyboard;

        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.storyboard.Begin();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es usted muy amable, me sirvió de mucho